# Read Excel file in web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

Currently I pass fully qualified path into the input control. I am passing it into web api via angularjs.

Instead of passing the path, I would like to just click the button, point to excel file on my local hard drive, pass that file into the web api, and then read the file inside web api.

Internet search results are not helping.

Here is my code.

```
public RowTable ProcessFile([FromBody] string filePath)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filePath))
    {
        throw new Exception("file path is null or empty.");
    }

    using (var pck = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage())
    {
        using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath))
        {
            pck.Load(stream);
        }
        var ws = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        .. process excel file in C# here..   
    }
```

... some more code here.
    }

html code..

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form">
    <input type="text" style="width:900px" placeholder="excel file path .." data-ng-model="filePath" />
    <input type="submit" data-ng-click="LoadFilePath()" value="Load Rates Table Excel File Data." />
</form>
```

AngularJS code ...

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('fileCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    //dataLoadError
    $scope.LoadFilePath = function () {
        $http
            .post('http://localhost:1229/api/Rates/processfile', '"' + $scope.filePath + '"')
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.Rates = data.Rates;
                $scope.InsertSQL = data.InsertSQL;
            })
            .error(function (data) {

            })
            ;
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://monox.mono-software.com/blog/post/Mono/233/Async-upload-using-angular-file-upload-directive-and-net-WebAPI-service/

Comment: Thanks DJ.. now I am trying to figure out how to process excel file once I am inside the controller but no luck so far.

Comment: DJ, this sample code neither is able to get the full qualified path on the local drive nor able to show how I can process the excel file.

Comment: For Security reasons, there is no way that server side you can get the full qualified path of the file uploaded., and in you question you ask that you want to not to use the filepath and instead the file itself.

Comment: correct. I am trying to figure out how can I use OfficeOpenXML.ExcelPackage to open the file and use it.

Comment: OK. You have to upload your file first to the server, there are many posts (as the one i linked) that can help you with that. Then you should either 1) save the file to disk on the server and the use your library to read the file. or 2) i dont know any other tools that can achive this, but http://epplus.codeplex.com/ can read excel files from an array of bytes (this allows not having to save the file, in cases you don't need to)

Comment: Thanks DJ. Appreicate all your help. Wish you posted your comments as answer, I would mark it as answer and upvote it.